# Can I make sbt compile additional sources with additional dependencies only for a specific task?

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-revolver

I am using spray revolver to test my application while writting code.

I would like to make a revolver run compile additional sources (e.g. /src/dev.scala or whatever) with additional dependencies. This is so when testing locally I can startup some external sevices we are using (e.g. cassandra) in the same vm without the need to have a proper environment set up.

Initially I tried setting these settings like this:

```
unmanagedSources in Revolver.reStart <<= (unmanagedSources in Compile) map { ss => ss :+ new File("/path/to/my/dev.scala") }

libraryDependencies in Revolver.reStart += ("org.cassandraunit" % "cassandra-unit" % "2.0.2.1")

mainClass in Revolver.reStart := Some("my.main.class.in.dev")
```

But when running the task,I just get that the main class doesn't exist.

Is there any way to make this work? The idea is to avoid having the cassandra-unit and code in dev.scala out of the compilation for tests & packaging.

Comment: normally this error comes when 
1. your path is not correct or
2. you dont have access to that file/folder i.e. permission issue.
3. if linux try ls -l and see that file belongs to which user. and if required provide permission using chmod or change user using chown command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That cannot work, because `Revolver.reStart` still uses `compile in Compile`, and `compile in Compile` uses `libraryDependencies`, *not* `libraryDependencies in Revolver.reStart`.

To do this, you need to defined an entirely different, custom *configuration* that extends your `Compile` configuration. In that configuration, say `"Localcompile"`, you can define your dependency with

```
unmanagedSources in Localcompile += new File("/path/to/my/dev.scala")

libraryDependencies += "org.cassandraunit" % "cassandra-unit" % "2.0.2.1" % "localcompile"
```

See http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Advanced-Configurations-Example.html for examples.